# is a MAC defined by a pseudo random generator secure?

Tags: mac, pseudo-random-generator

Let $ G:\{0,1\}^*\rightarrow\{0,1\}^*$ be a length doubling PRG, and let $ \Pi=(Gen,Mac,Vrfy)$ be the following MAC scheme:

> $ Gen $ on input $ 1^n$ uniformly samples and outputs $ k\leftarrow \{0,1\}^n $.
>
> $ Mac $ on input $k\in\{0,1\}^n$ and message $m\in \{0,1\}^n$ outputs
>   $ t=G(k||m) $.
>
> $ Vrfy $ on input $k\in\{0,1\}^n$, message $m\in \{0,1\}^n$ and a tag
>   $ t\in \{0,1\} ^{4n}$outputs 1 if $ t=G(k||m) $ and outputs 0
>   otherwirse.

Is $ \Pi $ necessarily a secure MAC scheme?

Comment: what kind of secure?

Comment: ...and what security definition for PRG are you using?

Comment: Adding to @Elias' point, what jumps out to me is that PRG definitions generally stipulate that the output to is secure *if* the input is sampled uniformly at random from the whole domain.